# Editing .tt file to change code generation does nothing hiting "run custom tool"

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio, code-generation, t4

I changed the .tt (template) file contained by a .edmx file to change the generation of the objects in my edmx diagram.

In my specific case I just wanted to add `[Serializable]` in my template to have it in every of my objects generated.

**I did add this line of code:**

```
<# Write("[Serializable]"); #>
```

**here, as it seems to be, the right place:**

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.UsingDirectives(inHeader: false, includeCollections: false)#>
<#
Write("[Serializable]");
#>
<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#>
```

For me it seems to be the right stuff, at the right place. Nothing too fancy here. But when I hit the "Run custom tool" option on my .tt file to re-generate the code, it simply does nothing.

How do I make it generate the code I need?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, Crawling the web for an answer, finding it myself and assuming I did not find the stuff on the internet, I'll put it here instead of deleting the question. Please be aware it is really stupid.

I did not have a high comprehension of the language used. Because of this I wrongly assumed

```
<#=Accessibility.ForType(complex)#> partial class <#=code.Escape(complex)#>
```

was the correct place to put my code generation over. It was not. The correct place is actualy:

```
<#=codeStringGenerator.EntityClassOpening(entity)#> : DataObject
```

Maybe this post will help someone having the same problem, just needind to be told to search somewhere else.

Have fun.